# How to substitute the following value?

Tags: python, django

Lets say this is my model

```
class A(models.Model):
name = models.CharField(max_length=10)
```

And I have this list:

```
l = ['name']
```

I want to do this:

```
a = A()
a.l[0] = 'Jack'
```

Why doesn't python substitute `name` from the `list` such that it becomes `a.name` ?
TIA

Comment: Because that's not how Python works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because Python looks up `a.l`, and if it were to find that, it would try to set its first element.

You're looking for setattr:

```
setattr(a, 'name', 'Jack')
```

or

```
setattr(a, l[0], 'Jack')
```

Comment: sorry I figured it and deleted the comment.